# "401 Unauthorized error" happened on haeroku application using github auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, github-api

Hi.
I have a laravel project deployed to heroku, but github Auth doesn’t go well.
When I access to “https://my-app.herokuapp.com/login/github”, heroku debugger on a browser returns a error as follows:

```
(1/1) ClientException
Client error: `GET https://api.github.com/user` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { “message”: “Bad credentials”, “documentation_url”: “https://developer.github.com/v3” }
```

I googled this error and found everybody says “Set the callback url correctly”, but I think I already did so.
Here are my codes and a screenshot of GitHub’s app settings page.

**`web.php`**

```php
Route::get('login/github', 'Auth\LoginController@ redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/github/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**`services.php`**

```
    ‘github' => [
        'client_id’ => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'), 
        'redirect’ => '/login/github/callback',
    ],
```

**`LoginController.php`**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
//my database access object
use App\Http\DAO;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

~~~~~~ 

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        //reading a stack trace, this line seems to occurs error.
        $github_user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();
        $github_id = [$github_user->user['login']][0];

        //if user already exists, get its User Model. Otherwise create a new Model.
        $dao = new DAO();
        $user = $dao->findUser($github_id);
        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $dao->addNewUser($github_id);
        }

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

[image]

What on earth is wrong? Of course the project works on a localhost. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It need that 'redirect’ url in services.php is full path to url, not relatively path. On a localhost, the path '/login/github/callback' is implicitly converted to 'localhost/login/github/callback', that's why I didn't notice. So the right code is:

```
    ‘github' => [
        'client_id’ => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'), 
        'redirect’ => 'https://*******.herokuapp.com/github/callback'
    ],
```